# How to do Multiple Column Sorting/Bookmarking for Duplicates in Emeditor?

Tags: multiple-columns, emeditor

[image]

I want to do a multiple column sorting in emeditor for duplicates and highlighting all lines of each duplicates.
But i do not seems to find a way around it.

The picture above speaks to what i intend to do.

I have tried the function "Delete/Bookmark Duplicate lines to no avail.

I will appreciate if there is a way around this.

Comment: Could you clarify the question - do you want to highlight duplicates in column 1, then additionally highlight duplicates in column 2?

Comment: I am looking to get duplicate files across the two (or more) columns.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by duplicate files. Your question is about lines.

Comment: There are 2 columns in the picture. I am looking for duplicates in second column (or rather if its more than one column). So i just want to "include all the lines in each duplicates" in the columns. that is what i want to do

Comment: Do you want to find all values that appear in both columns 1 and 2? In other words an intersection of columns 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The Join feature can be used for this case. "Join" basically means to find matching keys of two tables.

First, copy column 2 to another document. Then go to CSV | Advanced | Join... Make sure CSV Document 1 and 2 are your original document and the copy document. Then uncheck column 2 of the original in the list as shown below, because we copied column 2 to the new document.

[image]

Here's my table. I copied column 2 to another document, then used Join to get the duplicate numbers.

[image]

[image]

If you want to bookmark the duplicates in the original document, you should save the 1st column of the Join output to a file, then import it to Batch Find or Advanced Filter.

[image]